# Python String Method Conundrum

Tags: python, string, methods

The following code is supposed to print MyWords after removing SpamWords[0]. However; instead of returning "yes" it instead returns "None". Why is it returning "None"?

```
MyWords = "Spam yes"
SpamWords = ["SPAM"]
SpamCheckRange = 0
print ((MyWords.upper()).split()).remove(SpamWords[SpamCheckRange])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `remove` is a method that changes the mutable list object it's called on, and returns `None`.

```
l= MyWords.upper().split()
l.remove(SpamWords[SpamCheckRange])
# l is ['YES']
```

Perhaps you want:

```
>>> [word for word in MyWords.split() if word.upper() not in SpamWords]
['yes']
```

Comment: Technically, `l` is `['YES']`.

Comment: Is there another I can accomplish this without having to save to l?

Answer (score 0):

`remove` is a method of `list` (`str.split` returns a list), not `str`. It mutates the original list (removing what you pass) and returns `None`, *not* a modified list.